# how do i write git commit -am"this is my commit message" using ohmyzsh?

Tags: git

Just wondering how I write this using ohmyzsh? I know the shortcuts for most of the git commands, just not sure of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gca -m "this is my commit message"
```

Per https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh